# Single copy in memory

Tags: c

A compiler may choose to represent all identical string literals with a single copy in memory.  For example :

```
    /*Case 1*/
    char *s1 = "foo";
    char *s2 = "foo";

    printf("s1 points to : %p\n", s1);
    printf("s2 points to : %p\n", s2);
```

gives

```
s1 points to : 0x40063c
s2 points to : 0x40063c
```

However,

```
    /*Case 2*/
    char *s1 = "foo";
    char *s2 = (char[]){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};

    printf("s1 points to : %p\n", s1);
    printf("s2 points to : %p\n", s2);
```

gives

```
s1 points to : 0x40070c
s2 points to : 0x7ffe2866fcd0
```

This is perfectly OK as s1 points to some constant stuff while s2 does not.

But, is there a way to tell the compiler, in case2, that we actually wish to point s2 to some constant data - but maintain its declaration style - so that if the data pointed to by s2 is identical  to the data pointed to by s1, the compiler may proceed with a single copy of data in memory.

I tried

```
const char* s2=(char[]){'f','o','o','\0'};
```

with no luck.

Comment: Why not just do case 1!

Comment: @EdHeal : I may, but this puzzled me.

Comment: In your last try, it still won't be const because of the `(char[])` - try `(const char[])` instead (the compiler can't point it to `s1` because `s1` is immutable while the temporary pointer you get has to point to mutable data). This might at least give you data in your mapped file instead of data allocated in memory or on the stack. But I don't think the compiler is that smart to check also non-string constants for equality with strings...

Comment: @CherryDT I guess const is discarded with compound literals.

Comment: Any expectation that the pointers will be consistently equal/unequal will make your program fragile.

Comment: @CherryDT: I tried that already, but that didn't make a difference :-)

Comment: In case 1, s1 and s2 may be equal or not. It's entirely up to the compiler.

Comment: Why would you even want to do case 2? In case 2, `s1` and `s2` would not use the same memory address if `s1` is initially allocated for a string literal and `s2` is allocated for a char array. Remember you're casting `s2` from `&char[0]` to `char*`

Comment: @MichaelWalz : `s1 and s2 may be equal or not.` - I understand that, It is okay if it do not. Also I am not considering portable code here..

Comment: @sjsam look at the generated assembly output, you can do then conveniently [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Comment: @sjsam forget my second comment about the code not compiling, I just deleted it.

Answer (score 5):

If the ultimate goal is to get `s1 == s2`, just say so (`s2 = s1`) instead to trying to trick the compiler into doing this.

Comment: If it's absolutely required to do it in a way similar to how the OP requested, it might be possible to wrap the constants in a macro and use tricky preprocessing or actually write a second preprocessor which handles this. But I agree that there are probably better solutions and this may be a XY problem.

Comment: @CherryDT : Please check this on what makes an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I am definitely not considering the macro option here..

Comment: I know what an XY problem is, that's why I said it. It sounds very specific what you are asking, and is hard or impossible to solve this way, so it is likely that the actual *reason* why you need it (which you didn't tell yet) is something which *could* be solved, albeit through different means. (Hence also my macro suggestion.) This does by no means imply that you are a "n00b" as suggested in the example. This kind of situation happens to us on a weekly basis with other parties as well, who do know what they are doing, just like you.

Answer (score 2):

The C Standard says that

> 7 String literals, and compound literals with **const-qualified types**,
>   need not designate distinct objects.101)

and footnote 101

> 101) This allows implementations to share storage for string literals
>   and constant compound literals with the same or overlapping
>   representations.

So at least the compound literal should be defined like

```
const char* s2=( const char[]){'f','o','o','\0'};
                 ^^^^^
```

or

```
const char* s2=( const char[]){ "foo" };
                 ^^^^^
```

However it is better to compare the strings itself then their addresses because different compilers can have different options for setting this feature or such an option can be even absent.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get the same address for two seemingly different string literals is the optimizer concept known as "string pooling". If the compiler/linker can tell that the same string exists in multiple places of the code, it will only allocate it once. It can do so because string literals are read-only.

Unlike your compound literal `(char[]){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};` which is allocated in some read/write memory like for example on the stack.

If you make the compound literal itself `const`

`(const char[]){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};`

it should end up in the `.rodata` section, but the compiler might not be able to realize that it is equivalent to a string literal. If not, there will be no string pooling and you end up with duplicates in memory.

This however: `const char* s2=(char[]){'f','o','o','\0'};` does not make the compound literal itself read-only, it only affects the pointer.

Comment: I think the OP already knew about string pooling: "A compiler may choose to represent all identical string literals with a single copy in memory."

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. The creation of your strings is completely different from the view of the compiler.

Take this little program for example:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *s1 = "foo";
    char s2[] = {'f','o','o','\0'};
    char s3[] = "foo";
    return 0;
}
```

All three character arrays *might* look they are equal. But they aren't.

`s1` is a pointer to an array of characters, which is somewhere the compiler decides to put it (normally `.data`, `.cstring`, whatever).

`s2`, on the other hand, is an array of characters with the length of 4. The whole 4 bytes will land on the stack.

`s3` is equal to `s2`.

There is no safe way to achieve what you try to achieve, a (non-optimising) compiler might even produce two different strings for the first case.

The only safe way to get the behaviour, is by explicitly setting the pointers to the string you want them pointing to.

```
#include <assert.h>
static char FOOSTR[] = "foo";

int main(void)
{
    char *s1 = FOOSTR;
    char *s2 = FOOSTR;
    assert(s1 == s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind, `FOOSTR` is modifiable.

Comment: Appreciate the time :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, we can notice that your `s1` and `s2` are not the same. `"foo"` is a constant while `(char[]){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}` isn't. But even given that, often when creating an array inside a function even if it's a string the compiler will often just generate it on the stack on the fly. Especially since the string "foo" can be put on the stack with just one instruction:

```
$ cat foo2.c
void bar(const char *);
void
foo(void)
{
    char *x = (char[]){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};
    bar(x);
}
$ cc -O3 -S foo2.c
$ cat foo2.s
[...]
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $7303014, -4(%rbp)      ## imm = 0x6F6F66
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rdi
        callq   _bar
```

But. Let's see if we can convince the compiler to give us what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *s5 = (const char[]){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *s1 = "foo";
    char *s2 = "foo";
    char *s3 = (char[]){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};
    const char *s4 = (const char[]){'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'};

    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n", s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
    return 0;
}
```

On one machine:

```
$ cc -o foo foo.c && ./foo
0x400654
0x400654
0x7fff6cc15030
0x7fff6cc15040
0x400650
$ cc -O3 -o foo foo.c && ./foo
0x400620
0x400620
0x7fff20200960
0x7fff20200970
0x400634
$ cc -v
[...]
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
```

No luck. Even though `s5` is not on the stack and is a constant gcc isn't smart enough to figure out that it's the same as `"foo"`

Let's try another machine:

```
$ cc -o foo foo.c && ./foo
0x103819fa2
0x103819fa2
0x7fff5c3e6ac4
0x7fff5c3e6ab4
0x103819f9e
$ cc -O2 -o foo foo.c && ./foo
0x107fa1f9e
0x107fa1f9e
0x7fff57c5eaec
0x7fff57c5eae8
0x107fa1f9e
$ cc -v
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
```

Aha.. With enough optimization (-O1 didn't work) clang can figure it out.

It takes time and effort for the compiler to figure out that two constants are the same and I guess gcc doesn't bother.